# Append one table to another using kdb/q

Tags: sql, database, kdb, q-lang

I have a table that's got some values, and I would like to append another table to this one. The columns in the second table don't entirely match the first.

Please note I am using Q/KDB+ language to achieve this:

For example:

> Table 1
>
> Date TypeA TypeB TypeC Aggregate
>
> dt1   A B C ABC
>
> Table 2
>
> Header1 Header2
>
> TypeA     X
>
> TypeB     Y
>
> TypeC     Z

I would like my output to be

> Table3
>
> Date TypeA TypeB TypeC Aggregate
>
> dt1 A B C ABC
>
> (null) X Y  Z (null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t:([]date:enlist 2014.01.01;TypeA:enlist `A;TypeB:enlist `B;TypeC:enlist `C;Agg:enlist `ABC)

t2:([]header1:`TypeA`TypeB`TypeC;Header2:`X`Y`Z)

t uj enlist (!) . value flip t2

date       TypeA TypeB TypeC Agg
--------------------------------
2014.01.01 A     B     C     ABC
           X     Y     Z
```

Comment: a further simplification is possible, for the last line instead of using uj
q)t upsert (!) . value flip t2